# Is there a minus thickening operator on a metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $S$ be a metric space and $A$ a subset. For some $\varepsilon>0$ define the $\varepsilon$-thickening of $A$ as

$$A^{\varepsilon} = \left\{p \in S \mid \exists q \in A \;\;\text{with}\;\; d(p,q) < \epsilon\right\} = \bigcup_{q\in A} B_{\varepsilon}(q)$$

Does this thickening operation have an inverse for $\operatorname{diam}A>\varepsilon$, $A$ open? In what conditions would $((A^c)^\varepsilon)^c$ work for $A$ clopen?

Comment: One necessary condition for $((A^c)^\epsilon)^c$ to work is that $A$ be closed, because $(A^c)^\epsilon$ is always open.

Comment: @LeeMosher, on the other hand, if $A=B^\varepsilon$, $A$ is open because so is $B^\varepsilon$. So $A$ is clopen.

Answer (score 1):

My take on the matter would be to define first an open and a closed thickening operator.
Let $B(x,r)$ denote the open ball of radius $r$ around $x$. Define
$$
A^{r)} = \bigcup_{x \in A} B(x,r)
$$
for $r>0$ and for $r\geq 0$
$$
A^{r]} = \bigcap_{r' > r} A^{r')}
$$
Note $A^{r]}$ closed since $\bigcap_{r' > r} A^{r')} \supset \bigcap_{r' > r} \overline{A^{r'/2)}} = \bigcap_{r' > r} \overline{A^{r')}}  $. Further
\begin{align*}
A^{0)} &= A^{\circ}
\\
    A^{-r)} 
&=
    A^{\mathrm{C}\; r]\; \mathrm{C}}
=
    \left(\bigcap_{r' > r} A^{\mathrm{C}\; r']}\right)^{\mathrm{C}}
=
    \bigcup_{r' > r} A^{\mathrm{C}\; r']\;\mathrm{C}}
\\
    A^{-r]} 
&=
    A^{\mathrm{C}\; r)\; \mathrm{C}}
=
    \left(\bigcup_{x \in A} B(x,r) \right)^{\mathrm{C}}
=
    \bigcup_{x \in A} B(x,r)^{\mathrm{C}}
\end{align*}
Note that negative closed/open thickenings are open/closed.

For $ r \geq 0 $ and $s > 0$ note the inclusions
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:openThickeningIncl}
    A^{r)\;s)}, A^{r]\;s)} \subset A^{r+s)}
\end{equation}
that hold since
\begin{align*}
        A^{r)\;s)} \subset A^{r]\;s)} 
    &=
        \left( \bigcap_{r' > r} A^{r')} \right)^{s)}
\\
    &=
        \left\{ y\in X \mid \exists x \in \bigcap\nolimits_{r' > r} A^{r')} \colon |x\;y| < s\right\}
\\
    &=
        \left\{ y\in X \mid 
          \exists z \in A \colon |x\;z| < s\right\}
\\
    &=
        A^{r+s)}
\text{.}
\end{align*}
Further note the inclusion
\begin{equation}
    A^{r]\;s]}, A^{r]\;s]} \subset A^{r+s]}
\end{equation}
for $r,s \geq 0$ that holds due to
\begin{equation*}
        A^{r)\;s]} \subset A^{r]\;s]} 
    =
        \bigcap_{s' > s} A^{r]\; s')}
%\\
    \subset
        \bigcap_{s' > s + r} A^{s')}
%\\
    =
        A^{r]}
\text{.}
\end{equation*}
The inclusions also hold when $s$ is negative with a reverse inclusion sign. **Does anyone know if these definitions have shown up in the literature somewhere?**